# NSMatrix of buttons and Bind issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is my situation:

- a NSMatrix (in radio mode) that contains 4 buttons
- An object with properties "top","left","right","bottom" and the relative objectController.
- each button has state bind to one of the objectController key (top,left,right,bottom).

Radio mode makes me sure that only one button at once has state = on, my problem is that when i select a button the object property chained to the objcet controller goes to 1, but the previous one selected (now with state = off) doesn't go to 0 (the buttons view works correctly and only 1 button is active at time).

How can i obtain a on/off effect also on the bind object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding each button, you should bind the `selectedIndex` binding of the `NSMatrix` itself to a property in your model.

You'll need to change the way you store the selected edge in your code by using a single property:

```
typedef enum {
    TopEdge = 0,
    RightEdge,
    BottomEdge,
    LeftEdge
} Edge;

@property Edge currentEdge;
```

This will allow you to keep track of the currently selected index.

Comment: i just modified my code to follow your suggestion, but i'm really curious to understand why it can works with bind on single button